# protractor first() is working and get(0) is not

Tags: protractor

There's a troncated code of a page Object in protractor

that code is working :

```
var HomePage = function() {   
    this.publishedShows = element.all(by.repeater('show in showsHomePage'));
    this.getFirstShow = function(){
        return this.publishedShows.first();
    }
};
```

this one is not :

```
var HomePage = function() {   
    this.publishedShows = element.all(by.repeater('show in showsHomePage'));
    this.getFirstShow = function(){
        return this.publishedShows.get(0);
    }
};
```

I get this error :
Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("show in showsHomePage")

Anyone can inlight me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about `get(0)` vs `first()` - they are absolutely the same in terms of implementation. It is probably about the *timing*, [wait for the presence of the element](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) before making any action with it:

```
var elm = myPageObject.getFirstShow();
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);

// do smth with elm
```

Comment: many thanks. But isn't Protractor supposed to wait for any angular element before continuing the tests?

Comment: @MathieuBergeron in theory, yes, but in practice there are cases when you have to have these waits in the tests. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this solution, and still not working. Same error. Any other thought?

Answer (score 0):

alecxe does have a point about waiting for the element to be present and so you may want to the wait as mentioned or browser.waitForAngular();

What I have seen is that if you resolve a finder to a variable then this can get left in the unfulfilled promise state (even though the internals have resolved the query). What needs to be done is to resolve the promise and then you should be able to get the element you require:

So from your code:

```
`this.publishedShows = element.all(by.repeater('show in showsHomePage'));`
```

Will still be a promise and not publishedShows.

This returns items when I try your code (I have a slightly different repeater).

```
var HomePage = function() {   
    this.publishedShows = element.all(by.repeater('show in showsHomePage'));
    this.getFirstShow = function() {
            return this.publishedShows.then(function(items){
                =>return items[0].getText();
            });
    }
};

var hp = new HomePage();
=>expect(hp.getFirstShow()).toEqual('hello');
```

Obviously change your expect to what you want to check for and also the return too. Marked with =>

Ensure also that if you use any track by statement then you should look at the **by.exactRepeater** command to have an exact match on only the repeater part.
This worked for me, note the resolved promise returns an array of finders.